# Swift Package Collections doesn't work with an Entreprise GitHub account

Tags: swift, terminal, swift-package-manager, github-enterprise

I am trying to generate a package collections from a GitHub entreprise account, using the command line (follwing the steps on the official [doc](https://www.swift.org/blog/package-collections/)):

```
package-collection-generate packages.json collection.json
```

When I ran this command, the Terminal ask me for my user name, once provided it keeps runing without a result, until I stop it using `Ctl-C`

The `packages.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "Entreprise iOS packages",
    "overview": "This collection contains the entreprise Swift packages.",
    "author": {
        "name": "Swift packages"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "iOS"
    ],
    "packages": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.entreprise.com/[ORGANISATION]/[REPO].git"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have also ttried to integrate my access token and user name in the url like this:

```
https://[UserName]:[AccessToken]@https://github.entreprise.com/[ORGANISATION]/[REPO].git
```

I have also tried to use the SSH url, with no success.

```
git@github.entreprise.com:[ORGANISATION]/[REPO].git
```

I can import the same package using Xcode Packages

I have SSH configured on my machine

I have tried to use both Private and Public access to the repo

With the same setup, I can create a collection using a non-entreprise GitHub account.

Maybe I am missing something or Swift Package Collection doesn't work with a GitHub Entreprise account!

Can you please advice what to do here?

Answer (score 0):

You talk about a Github enterprise account but give a completely wrong URL in multiple places in your question (including your packages.json). Double-check that.

Comment: Can you please adivse? I think using `github.entreprise.com` instead if `github.com` is enough!

Comment: It's spelled "enterprise" and "enterprise.com" is not Github's domain and it doesn't look like "entreprise" is in use as it's parked. Do you own "entreprise.com"?